# NumPy save some arrays at once

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I working on different shapes of arrays and I want to save them all with `numpy.save`, so, consider I have

```
mat1 = numpy.arange(8).reshape(4, 2)
mat2 = numpy.arange(9).reshape(2, 3)
numpy.save('mat.npy', numpy.array([mat1, mat2]))
```

It works. But when I have two matrices with one dimension of same size it's not working.

```
mat1 = numpy.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
mat2 = numpy.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
numpy.save('mat.npy', numpy.array([mat1, mat2]))
```

It causes
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,4) into shape (2)`

And note that the problem caused by `numpy.array([mat1, mat2])` and not by `numpy.save`

I know that such array is possible:

`>> numpy.array([[[1, 2]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]])
    array([[[1, 2]], [[1, 2], [3, 4]]], dtype=object)`

So, all of what I want is to save two arrays as `mat1` and `mat2` at once.

Comment: Have you considered using `np.savez` or pickle with a binary protocol instead?  `savez` saves multiple arrays, `save` only saves a single array.

Comment: It works on my computer. What version of python are you using?

Comment: If the first dimension of `mat1` and `mat2` are the same, `np.array(...)` produces this error.  You can get around this error by initializing a `np.empty((2,),object)` array, and filling it with the element arrays.  Also do that if all the dimensions are the same (to prevent concatenation).

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you'd like to save multiple arrays in the same format as [`np.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), use [`np.savez`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html).

For example:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4)
arr2 = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
np.savez('mat.npz', name1=arr1, name2=arr2)

data = np.load('mat.npz')
print data['name1']
print data['name2']
```

If you have several arrays, you can expand the arguments:

```
import numpy as np

data = [np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4), np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)]
np.savez('mat.npz', *data)

container = np.load('mat.npz')
data = [container[key] for key in container]
```

Note that the order is not preserved.  If you do need to preserve order, you might consider using `pickle` instead.

If you use `pickle`, be sure to specify the binary protocol, otherwise the you'll write things using ascii pickle, which is particularly inefficient for numpy arrays.  With a binary protocol, `ndarray`s more or less pickle to the same format as `np.save`/`np.savez`.  For example:

```
# Note: This is Python2.x specific. It's identical except for the import on 3.x
import cPickle as pickle
import numpy as np

data = [np.arange(8).reshape(2, 4), np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)]

with open('mat.pkl', 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(data, outfile, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

with open('mat.pkl', 'rb') as infile:
    result = pickle.load(infile)
```

In this case, `result` and `data` will have identical contents and the order of the input list of arrays will be preserved.

Comment: Consider I have list of arrays and I want to save them all, and after that to load all.

Comment: Also... there is solution for the general problem I wrote?

Comment: @Dubon - I'm not quite sure what you're referring to by "the general problem".  If you mean writing/reading arbitrary python objects to/from disk, `pickle` is what you're looking for.

Comment: The general problem is that I can't do `numpy.array([arr1, arr2])` if `arr1.shape[0] = arr2.shape[0]` if I don't want broadcasting.

Comment: @Dubon - No, there's no way to make a numpy array have a different shape along a dimension.  `ndarray`s have to have a consistent shape. (Internally, an `ndarray` is a memory buffer with a simple description of shape/strides/type.  "Ragged" arrays can't be described that way.) If you want "ragged" arrays, use a list of arrays instead. A single array can't contain arrays of different shapes. (Well, excluding object arrays, but you _really_ don't want those.)

Comment: @Dubon - You're getting an object array.  It's not a "real" array in the same sense as the others.  It's basically a very inefficient `list`.  You're better off using a `list` instead of creating an object array.  As you've noted, this particular result is a _1D_ array of other arrays.  It won't broadcast like a 2D or 3D array because it's 1D.  You also won't be able to use mathematical operations in quite the same way (or rather, you'll be hit with some nasty surprises).  If you're not already very familiar with `numpy`, don't use object arrays.

Comment: To complement Joe's comment and see why he is right when he says *It's not a "real" array in the same sense as the others* , see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426587/what-is-going-on-behind-this-numpy-selection-behavior).

Comment: @JoeKington When you say order is not preserved. Does it mean in the list or in the numpy arrays?

Answer (score 5):

Small addition: if you'd like to use `numpy.savez()` and preserve names associated with the saved arrays (instead of `arr_0, arr_1, ...`) you can pass a dictionary as `**kwargs` using the [double-star operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

```py
d = {}
d['a'] = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
d['b'] = np.random.randint(10, size=5)
print(d)
# {'a': array([8, 9, 5, 0, 0]), 'b': array([1, 7, 6, 9, 2])}

np.savez("test", **d)
container = np.load("test.npz")

e = {name: container[name] for name in container}
print(e)
# {'a': array([8, 9, 5, 0, 0]), 'b': array([1, 7, 6, 9, 2])}
```