# How to save a list of numpy arrays into a single file and load file back to original form

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tf.keras

I am currently trying to save a list of numpy arrays into a single file, an example of such a list can be of the form below

```py
import numpy as np
np_list = []
for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        np_list.append(np.random.randn(64))
    else:
        np_list.append(np.random.randn(32, 64))
```

I can combine all of them using into a single file using `savez` by iterating through list but is there any other way? I am trying to save weights returned by the function `model.get_weights()`, which is a list of `ndarray` and after retrieving the weights from the saved file I intend to load those weights into another model using `model.set_weights(np_list)`. Therefore the format of the list must remain the same. Let me know if anyone has an elegant way of doing this.

Comment: the answer here seems to do the trick [NumPy save some arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35133517/7537870)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy save some arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35133317/numpy-save-some-arrays-at-once)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would go with `np.save` and `np.load` because it's platform-independent, faster than `savetxt` and works with lists of arrays, for example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = [
    np.arange(100),
    np.arange(200)
]
np.save('a.npy', np.array(a, dtype=object), allow_pickle=True)
b = np.load('a.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

This is the documentation for [np.save](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [np.load](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.load.html). And in this answer you can find a better discussion [How to save and load numpy.array() data properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439701/how-to-save-and-load-numpy-array-data-properly/55058828)

### Edit

Like @AlexP mentioned `numpy >= v1.24.2` does not support arrays with different sizes and types, so that's why the casting is necessary.

Comment: This does not work for a list of numpy arrays

Comment: @DVK you can set `allow_pickle=True` and it works.

Comment: Careful with this approach.  `save` will do `np.array(a)` before saving.  So `b` will be an array, not a list.  And as others have found out, making an array from a list of arrays has its hidden dangers.  Don't do it naively.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, that's True! Thanks for the insight.

Comment: It does not let me answer, so I go here. It did not worked for me. The solution was to use `np.savez`. I would do the complete answer if I could comment.

Comment: using numpy 1.24.2 and it no longer works if storing arrays of different size or different type. Use instead: np.save('a.npy', np.array(a,dtype=object), allow_pickle=True)

Comment: @AlexP that's true. I'll update the answer.